# 'At a glance, at a touch' - Is it weird if I use this expression?

Tags: word-usage

I've seen that 'at a glance' is a quite widely used in many texts. However, it refers to eye or optical something whatsoever. - Sorry, I'm not a native speaker ;(. I'd like to apply it to touch sensation.

Just like "at a glance", which means "If you see something in a very short time", I'd like to use "at a touch" to express "If you touch something in a very short time, you can feel something something something."

I googled "at a touch" to find out if it reflects my idea, but it seems it is uncommon to use it. Finally I got into this site, then I clicked previous question "What does 'touch' mean in “It opened at a touch”?" to check if my idea is ok to go, but context there seems little bit different from my intention.

Example: "At a glance, you can feel exotic color, at a touch, you feel extreme comfort."

Does it sound so weird to native english users?

Comment: You need to provide context. Your example of *it opened at a touch* is fine. But if that's not how you want to use it yourself, then how do you want to use it?

Comment: It reads like a cheesy advertisement, but I think that is what you want? When following "at a glance", meaning is obvious.

Comment: TBH, the whole thing is a bit odd. Perhaps employ a native speaker with experience in advertising.  Straplines/slogans are generally very brief, punchy, and memorable. Not an entire story!

Answer (score 0):

It would be odd because it's already part of another idiom,

> **At the touch** of a button

You use this to indicate that some mechanical or electronic device does all the actual work, and all a person needs to do is activate the system.

> The new Kitchen Buddy is so intelligent, that, **at the touch of a button**, it can prepare a full seven-course meal and do all the washing up.

We would need more context to say what would sound right, but some suggestions:

> At the briefest touch ...
>
> With just a touch (of your hand) ...
>
> The lightest touch was enough ...

and various others.

Comment: Thanks for giving me reasons why the expression I intended to use is odd. Let me clarify my idea with an example, "At a glance, you can feel exotic color, at a touch, you feel extreme comfort." Might be weird in this sense as well?

Comment: @YunHwanKim because it's parallel phrasing its fine.

Comment: Please always give examples up front. I have edited your question.